# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAseClientDriver

Tags: nhibernate, sap-ase

My Configuration is like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
      </property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAseClientDriver
      </property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        ********
      </property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting this exception: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAseClientDriver while creating configuration.
Could somebody please help me figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I changed the driver to OleDbDriver.

```
  <property name="connection.driver_class">
    NHibernate.Driver.OleDbDriver
  </property>
```